# java generics - ensure objects returned by factory methods relate to the same type

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code:

```
interface Factory<T extends A<S>, S extends B> {
    T getA();
    S getB();
}

...

interface A<T extends B> {
    void doB(T b);
}

...

interface B { }
```

Now what I am trying to do is a method getFactory that returns me arbitrary Factory-ies. The Factory type parameters ensure (as far as I can see) that I can call

```
Factory<?????> factory = getFactory();
factory.getA().doB(factory.getB());
```

But I cannot get the right type parameters. Is it at all possible?

I tried

```
Factory<? extends A<? extends B>, ? extends B> factory = getFactory();
```

But then it ? extends B and ? extends B are 2 different things, even though Factory class guarantees they are the same!

Comment: it should be possible to use something like `Factory<T extends B> getFactory(Class<T> clazz)` templates to create different factories for different kind of objects. As documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html

Comment: but i don't know the class when i call getFactory

Comment: it depends on the implementation of `getFactory`. Why didn't you paste `getFactory` method signature?

Comment: hmm i don't know the signature, i want getFactory to be as much generic as possible, it generates different Factory objects based on some conditions

Comment: If you don't know the class when you call getFactory at run time, then how do you expect to get factory of the right type? Type parameters are erased at run time.

Answer (score 4):

First, let me slightly clarify your example code. Let it be like this:

```
interface Factory<SpecificHandler extends Handler<SpecificMessage>, SpecificMessage extends Message> {
    SpecificHandler getHandler();
    SpecificMessage getMessage();
}


interface Handler<T extends Message> {
    void handle(T b);
}


interface Message { }
```

Thus, you have a factory, that can produce a message and a handler for that specific message. The following code does not work because compiler is too lazy to check, that both handler and message came from the same factory:

```
Factory<? extends Handler<?>, ? extends Message> factory = getFactory();
Handler<? extends Message> handler = factory.getHandler();
Message message = factory.getMessage();
handler.handle(message);//error
```

To solve this problem you must bind type parameters to the same actual type. But you don't know the exact type.
The only possible solution i can imagine:

```
<T extends Message> void doWork() {
    Factory<? extends Handler<T>, T> x = getFactory();
    Handler<T> handler = x.getHandler();
    T message = x.getMessage();
    handler.handle(message);
}

void test() {
    doWork();
}
```

Here we introduce a meaningless type parameter T to our method signature just to bind both handler and factory to the same message type.

Comment: hmm sorry but could you please provide a definition of getFactory() that would be compatible with above code and capable of generating arbitrary Factories?

Comment: Aw... missed that part of code. I used something like this while testing with ide:
    `<T extends Message> Factory<? extends Handler<T>, T> getFactory() { return null; }`
or even
    `Factory<?, ?> getFactory() { return null; }`
and didn't try to create any instance of a factory.

Answer (score 0):

If `getFactory()` returns a Factory, S extends B> and you do not know A or B you can use:

```
Factory<?, ?> factory = getFactory();
```

but then you won't know the `T` and `S` types obviously so you could realy just do:

```
Factory factory = getFactory();
```

You could also use:

```
Factory<A<B>, B> factory = getFactory();
```

and then you would know the return types of the Factory methods wold be A and B respectively.

Comment: Factory<?, ?> factory = getFactory(); factory.getA().doB(factory.getB()); -- this gives me an error: doB(capture#301 of ?) in A<capture#301 of ?> cannot be applied to (B)

Comment: Factory factory = getFactory();
gives me unchecked warning on factory.getA().doB(factory.getB());

Comment: Factory<A<B>, B> <-- but i don't know the types A and B in advance, i want getFactory to support any possible types

Comment: You do know the types of the interfaces A and B. Those are the ones you specified as the bounds of the generics...

Comment: That said, if you realy don't know or want to know the generic types of the factory then why are you using generics at all? You could just specify the interfaces as the return types...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have factory method which can return object with various templates, I recommend declaring `getFactory` as a generic method like so

`public <T extends A<S>, S extends B> Factory<T, S> getFactory() {`

Then you can call it like this:

`Factory<MyClass1, MyClass2> someFact = getFactory();`

provided that these things hold true:

- `MyClass1` extends `A<MyClass2>`
- `MyClass2` extends `B`

Of course the `getFactory()` implementation must return the correct instance otherwise it will lead to runtime class cast exceptions.

Comment: but i don't know MyClass1, MyClass2 in advance, and do not want to know them. I only want to call factory.getA().doB(factory.getB()), and Factory interface type signature has enough information (as it seems to me) to allow me to provide getFactory method that allows me to do the above.

Comment: Yeah, well that won't work, because wildcards information is not retained between sentences. You can declare `doB` as generic method and have the compiler do the cast. That's the most you can do in this situation.